# Redirect from Modal Box to Non-modal page

Tags: c#, sharepoint, modal-dialog

I have a Modal Box that opens by clicking a HyperLink.

In the Modal Box I fill out information used to create a new site. When I click the button "Create Project" I want the Modal Box to close and the page to redirect to the new site.

I have tried Response.Redirect(url); but this will open the new site in the Modal Box.

How do I solve this?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent page could retrieve the “Call-back” parameters, so we can receive this token and redirect.

Perhabs this solution will help you allong:

http://www.chakkaradeep.com/post/Using-the-SharePoint-2010-Modal-Dialog.aspx

Comment: Sorry for the late comment but other tasks came up. I've read the post but I still don't understand how to use the callback function. Is the callback function supposed to be used on the modal box page?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I was working with the page that the modal box displays, when I should have been working with the page that creates the modal box. D'oh!